# Equivalent to Ruby's to_i(36) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, radix

```
"y851sq2vh4pf".to_i(36) #4504900070017571091
```

but

```
parseInt("y851sq2vh4pf",36) //4504900070017571300
```

How can I implement the Ruby to_i(36) function in Javascript? Why are the behaviors different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have 64 bit integers, it only has [`double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision) which loses accuracy for integers after `9007199254740992` (2<sup>53</sup>)

Use a Big Number library like http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/

Comment: Actually ruby autmatically switches from Fixnum to Bignum when needed.

Comment: @steenslag feel free to edit, I don't know anything about ruby.